# moving circle in square direction using keyframes in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

My circle is not moving in square direction using keyframes in advance css.Please tell me why it is not going in right direction.And do we use relative inside the parent card?

And do tell me if there is any useful sight to understand this concept better.

```css
.card{
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  margin: 20px 20%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.box
{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius : 50%;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}
@keyframes slide{
  0%
  {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  25%{
     top: 0;
     right: 90%;
  }
  50%{
    right: 0;
    bottom: 75%;
  }
  75%{
    left: 75%;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  100%{
     left: 0;
     top: 75%;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="card">
  <div class="box"></div>
    <div>
```

Comment: It looks like it's animating exactly as your keyframes tell it to, what did you expect to see it do? Because a rectangle is not a direction, it's an entire 2d shape, so "my circle is not moving in square direction" is not really information that lets people know what you're trying to achieve. One thing you might have forgotten to take into account is that if you don't change values, they stay _whatever they were before_ and may end up getting mixed, so you'll probably want to express you path _only_ in terms of `top` and `left` (and then use some `calc(...)` rules to make sure you compensate)

Answer (score 1):

This gets you there. In this case using 75% works since your box is 400px square and the ball has a diameter of 100px. As mentioned, using `calc` would be ideal, but I seem to remember that `calc` does not work in animations. Verifying that now...

Here is an example (not mine) that uses `calc` in keyframes but they are very simple and do not involve capturing the width of an element: [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/ausnichts/pen/mQexLv)

Here is another [example](https://valhead.com/2017/07/21/animating-with-css-variables/) from 2017 that uses `calc` in keyframes via CSS variables. At the time of that writing, this was not fully supported by all browsers but may have changed by now.

Also worth noting that my first snippet is not pixel-perfect. This is due to the 2px border on the ball. See the second snippet which removes that border.

From this, one can deduce that making the ball 96px with a 2px border would give you a pixel-perfect solution while maintaining the 2px border.

And finally, here is a good source for more information regarding animations: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

```css
.card {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  margin: 20px 20%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  25% {
    top: 0;
    left: 75%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 75%;
    left: 75%;
  }
  75% {
    top: 75%;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="box"></div>
<div>
```

Border removed from ball (pixel perfect):

```css
.card {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  margin: 20px 20%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  /*border: 2px solid black;*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  25% {
    top: 0;
    left: 75%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 75%;
    left: 75%;
  }
  75% {
    top: 75%;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="box"></div>
<div>
```